# How to prevent iphone microphone to record played sound?

Tags: iphone, signal-processing, audio-recording, microphone, audioqueue

I am currently working on an app that needs to record and and play at the same time, but only a given beep at a given frequency. All this works fine by using avaudioplayer to play the sound and audioqueue to emit at a required frequency. The aim would be to pick up the signal from other devices and process them.

Unfortunately each time I play my sound I also trigger the processing since the app "hears itself". I was wondering if there is a way to somehow cancel this out with or without serious signal processing / software tricks etc.

My solution now is to use a flag to make the app deaf while the avaudioplayer plays the sound then it delegates the finishing even to change the flag. Well.. it is not really accurate :(

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What's not accurate about temporarily reducing or zero-ing the mic input volume?  People's inner ears do that when they talk.

Comment: I do not know when the audio is _totally_ finished, even if I use avaudioplayer delegate, it fires "too early". Right now I assigned a timer but its duration is again a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something very similar to [AEC (acoustic echo cancellation)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_cancellation#Acoustic_echo_cancellation) - this can be quite tricky to implement, but essentially it's an adaptive filter which cancels out the audio from the speaker.

Comment: Interesting, I will look into it, maybe this helps. Thanks!